# combine sql queries into one using IF

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three sql queries which retrieves results from different conditions and I want to combine these queries into one using IF statement.how can i do that?

Comment: So many things wrong here..

Comment: this is not my full code.i just want to get an idea about how to combine my two quiries

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregates and group by to get the total.  This will be much faster, and you won't need to fetch all of the data in order to get the counts (your current queries are doing that).

This should work if it's OK to have the results in rows:

```
SELECT if(client_status = 1, "active", "inactive"), count(*)
FROM client
WHERE (client_status = 1 OR client_status = 0)
GROUP BY client_status
```

Comment: thanks if we have 3 or four queries depends on different where conditions then how can i merge them?

Comment: i have modified my question.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's hard for me to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: i have posted another question and i have answered it too.i need to do it in a most efficient way.that.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522521/combining-multiple-sql-queries-into-single-query/22522894?noredirect=1#22522894