# Combining Multiple SQL Queries Into Single Query

Tags: sql

I have three queries as below and I need to combine them into one. Does any body know how to do that?

```
$myTasks = "";
$query = "SELECT taskID_PK " .
            "FROM tasks t " . 
            "LEFT JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK ".
            "LEFT JOIN task_attachments a ON a.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK ".
            "LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = t.assignByID_FK ".
            " WHERE TRUE AND isArchive != 1 AND taskStatus = 1 AND ta.clientID_FK  = {$G_CLIENID} AND categoryID_FK !=0  group by taskID_PK ";

$RawData = db::select($query);
$myTasks= count($RawData);

$closeTasks = "";
$query = "SELECT taskID_PK,taskTitle,taskDescn,categoryID_FK,priority,date_format(createDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as createDate,ticketID_FK,
            date_format(dueDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as dueDate ,assignByID_FK,createTime,  taskStatus,closedDate,employeeName ,attachmentID_PK " .
            "FROM tasks t " . 
            "LEFT JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK ".
            "LEFT JOIN task_attachments a ON a.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK ".
            "LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = t.assignByID_FK ".
            " WHERE TRUE AND isArchive != 1 AND (taskStatus != 1 ){$taskCreateClause} AND categoryID_FK !=0  group by taskID_PK ";
$RawData = db::select($query);
$closeTasks = count($RawData);

$workLoad ="";
$query = "SELECT taskID_PK,taskTitle,taskDescn,categoryID_FK,priority,date_format(createDate, '%m/%d/%Y') as createDate,ticketID_FK,
            date_format(dueDate, '%m/%d/%Y') as dueDate ,assignByID_FK,createTime,  taskStatus,closedDate,employeeName ,clientID_FK " .
            "FROM task_assignee ta " . 
            "LEFT JOIN tasks t ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK ".
            "LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = ta.clientID_FK ".
            " WHERE TRUE AND taskStatus = 1  ";
$RawData = db::select($query);
$workLoad = count($RawData);
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "Combine into one" You can use the [union operator][1] to combine the bottom two queries into one, because they are selecting the same fields. What would you want to do with the first one?

  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: if i have same set of fields in first one then how can i combine those  with out using UNION

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like the "in" operator my be what you're looking for? If you need to select something in the second query based on the first, you can do something like "select id, title from tasks where id in (select taskID_PK from tasks...". Is that what you're going for?

Comment: above three queries returns different results and i want to display count of each results in a html table.is there any way to combine those using IF?

Answer (score 0):

Okay now that I understand the question, how about something like this:

```
select a.taskID_PK,
     (Select count(*)) .
        "FROM tasks t " . 
        "LEFT JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK ".
        "LEFT JOIN task_attachments a ON a.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK ".
        "LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = t.assignByID_FK ".
        " WHERE TRUE AND isArchive != 1 AND taskStatus = 1 AND ta.clientID_FK  =    {$G_CLIENID} AND categoryID_FK !=0  
         and task_ID_PK = a.taskID_PK) as Count1,
         group by taskID_PK 

....
from tasks
```

Select the main ID, then 3 independent select statements return a count and joined up with the ID at the beginning.

Comment: I combined my quries like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
       (SELECT(COUNT(DISTINCT t.taskID_PK))
                FROM tasks t
                LEFT JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK
                LEFT JOIN task_attachments a ON a.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK
                LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = t.assignByID_FK
                 WHERE TRUE AND isArchive != 1 AND taskStatus = 1 AND categoryID_FK !=0)as activetasks,
        (SELECT(COUNT(DISTINCT t.taskID_PK))
                FROM tasks t
                LEFT JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK
        LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = t.assignByID_FK
                 WHERE TRUE AND isArchive != 1 AND taskStatus = 1 AND ta.clientID_FK=1 AND categoryID_FK !=0)as mytasks,
       (SELECT(COUNT(DISTINCT t.taskID_PK))
                FROM tasks t
                LEFT JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK
        LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = t.assignByID_FK
                WHERE TRUE AND isArchive != 1 AND taskStatus != 1 AND categoryID_FK !=0)as cloastasks,
        (SELECT(COUNT(t.taskID_PK))
        FROM task_assignee ta
                LEFT JOIN tasks t ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK
                LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = ta.clientID_FK
                 WHERE TRUE AND taskStatus = 1)as workload,
        (SELECT(COUNT(DISTINCT t.taskID_PK))
                FROM tasks t
                LEFT JOIN task_assignee ta ON ta.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK
                LEFT JOIN task_attachments a ON a.taskID_FK = t.taskID_PK
                LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID_PK = t.assignByID_FK
                 WHERE TRUE AND isArchive = 1 AND categoryID_FK !=0)as archivetasks.
```

I combined my queries and I want to know is there any better way to combine those to improve efficiency?